# Clojure compojure middleware and arrow syntax

Tags: clojure, compojure

I am trying to understand compojure middlewares :

The following code is from the [compojure template](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure-template/blob/master/resources/leiningen/new/compojure/handler.clj) :

```
(def app
  (wrap-defaults app-routes site-defaults))
```

Is it equivalent to the following ?

```
(def app
  (-> app-routes
      (wrap-defaults api-defaults)))
```

I am unsure about this since in the following code `my-middleware2` is called before `my-middleware1`

```
(def app
  (-> api-routes
      (wrap-defaults api-defaults)
      (my-middleware1)
      (my-middleware2)))
```

Comment: Compojure brings some convenient macros on top of Ring. To be precise, Middlewares are Ring's ones, not Compojure's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct:

```clj
(def app
  (wrap-defaults app-routes site-defaults))
```

Is equivalent to:

```clj
(def app
  (-> app-routes
      (wrap-defaults api-defaults)))
```

The arrow is called the [Thread-First Macro](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E) and allows you to write nested s-expressions in a linear way.

In your second example, it makes sense that `my-middleware2` is called before `my-middleware1` when an HTTP request comes in. You are creating a [Ring Handler](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/wiki/Concepts), not calling the middleware directly.

```clj
(def app
  (-> api-routes
    (wrap-defaults api-defaults)
    my-middleware1
    my-middleware2))
```

Is expanded to:

```clj
(def app
  (my-middleware2 (my-middleware1 (wrap-defaults app-routes api-defaults))))
```

When an HTTP request comes in, `my-middleware2` handles it first, does something to it (i.e. extracts the session data), and then passes it along to the next middleware until one of them returns an HTTP response.

Note: I took out the parens from `(my-middleware1)` and `(my-middleware2)`. When used like that it means that `my-middlware1` is a function that when called with no arguments, returns a middleware function. This might be what you wanted but is not common practice.

Comment: Thanks it helps. And would a thread last macro make sense here ? What would be the common practice here ? Ex. when adding a json parser, where should it be ?

Comment: Thread last macro is not usually used with Ring middleware since the convention is `(middleware handler options)`.

Comment: For JSON look at `(wrap-json-body handler)` from https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-json and you should add it before any other handler that assumes the bodys request is a Clojure data structure.

Comment: this answered a lot of my questions about middleware and the thread-first, thanks a lot guys! =)